# javasccript find element in array of object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of objects and one of the properties of each object is TheID.
Something like this:

```
TheArray[0].TheID = 34;
TheArray[1].TheID = 2352;
...
```

I'm looking to return the index of the array that contains the property TheID I'm looking for.

I have a classic for-loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < TheArray.length; i++) {
   if (TheArray[i].TheID = MagicNumber) { var TheIndex = i; } 
}
retun TheIndex;
```

This works but it still has to loop through the entire array, even after it found TheIndex.

How do you stop the loop after the it found TheIndex?

Thanks.

Comment: Throw it into a function, then return the variable. It'll drop out of the loop. Or use break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `break` to leave the loop:

```
var TheIndex;
for (var i = 0; i < TheArray.length; i++) {
   if (TheArray[i].TheID == MagicNumber) {
      TheIndex = i;
      break;
   } 
}
return TheIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (TheArray[i].TheID = MagicNumber) { return i; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Break;` or `return;` within a loop to stop it once you have found what you are looking for. There is no other way to search arrays/objects for specific property values. You could consider re factoring your code entirely to avoid unnecessary performance sinks like this but that isn't always feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is from a while ago, another alternative that might be useful if you do many such searches would be to loop once an index based on your search criteria.

e.g. do this once:

```
var idToIdx={};
for (var i = 0; i < TheArray.length; i++) {
   idToIdx['I'+TheArray[i].TheID] = i
   } 
}
```

and then just use for `idToIdx['I'+ MagicNumber]` as  many times as you need.