# Query JSON node value with another node's value

Tags: javascript, json

New to JSON so I'll do my best here.  I have a JSON object called HUDS. Below are 2 sample nodes (by the way, can I call these nodes in JSON like in XML?).

```
var HUDS = [
{
    "DISTRICT": "100",
    "BIOS": "BROWN",
    "AREA_KM": "3663.158164",
    "AREA_MI": "1414.347616",
    "NAME": "100",
    "REG": "1",
    "ACRES": "905182",
    "EMU_Name": "Purcell",
    "Shape_Leng": "299746.4938",
    "Shape_Area": "3663158164",
},
{
    "DISTRICT": "101",
    "BIOS": "THIER",
    "AREA_KM": "1507.774765",
    "AREA_MI": "582.152762",
    "NAME": "101",
    "REG": "1",
    "ACRES": "372578",
    "EMU_Name": "Salish",
    "Shape_Leng": "229150.0655",
    "Shape_Area": "1507774766",
}
```

]

I have a drop down form that will be used to specify a value specific to the "BIOS" field in my JSON.  For example the user could select BROWN from the dropdown menu.

I'd then like to create a var that can be used to fill in a div.  For example when the user selects BROWN I'd like my div to fill with the value from "EMU_Name"

I know this is wrong but maybe it conveys what I am going for

```
function dropDownAction(){
var tempBios=document.BIOSForm.BIOS.value;
var tempEmuValue=HUDS.BIOS==tempBios.EMU_Name;
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=tempEmuValue;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [javasccript find element in array of object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234211/javasccript-find-element-in-array-of-object)

Comment: Your problem is not related to JSON. You are merely trying to find a Javascript object inside a Javascript array.

Comment: thanks...  the solution below work great for referencing my Javascript array.  Felix, whats the difference between JSON and a Javascript Array?

Comment: A JavaScript array is a data type in JavaScript. For example `var a = [];` is an array. JSON is a textual data exchange format, much like XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    <form name="BIOSForm">
        <select name="BIOS" onchange="dropdownaction();">
            <option value="BROWN">BROWN</option>
            <option value="THEIR">THEIR</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="emuname">

    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var HUDS = [
    {
        "DISTRICT": "100",
        "BIOS": "BROWN",
        "AREA_KM": "3663.158164",
        "AREA_MI": "1414.347616",
        "NAME": "100",
        "REG": "1",
        "ACRES": "905182",
        "EMU_Name": "Purcell",
        "Shape_Leng": "299746.4938",
        "Shape_Area": "3663158164",
    },
    {
        "DISTRICT": "101",
        "BIOS": "THIER",
        "AREA_KM": "1507.774765",
        "AREA_MI": "582.152762",
        "NAME": "101",
        "REG": "1",
        "ACRES": "372578",
        "EMU_Name": "Salish",
        "Shape_Leng": "229150.0655",
        "Shape_Area": "1507774766",
    }
    ]

    function dropdownaction(){
        for(var x=0;x<HUDS.length;x++){
            var tempBios = document.BIOSForm.BIOS.value;
            if(tempBios == HUDS[x].BIOS){
                document.getElementById("emuname").innerHTML = HUDS[x].EMU_Name;
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    </script>
```